# Edit css file in swift/obj c without using javascript

Tags: html, ios, css, objective-c, swift

I want to change the font/font-color/font-size of an html page. I have converted the css file to a string using String(contentsOfFile). Can I use regEx or something similar to edit the css data. Here is a sample of the css file

```
.calibre {

    color: #000;
    display: block;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 5pt;
    margin-right: 5pt;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    text-align: justify
}
```

I have also tried converting this string(of Css file) to a Dictionary using ESCssParser. However, when I convert that dictionary(after changing the font size) to a string, the formatting is different. An example of a difference is that #idSelector would become "#idSelector". I am in the assumption that these changes will affect the css file. Am I wrong?

Is there any other approach I can take to edit the Css file?
Thanks!

Comment: You can load the file into a string, parse the string, change what you want to change then save the css file again. Your page would need to be reloaded for the user to see the changes though, why are you trying to do it this way?

Comment: I would change the css before loading the page. For example, the user choose a size(small, med, or large) Then when he dismisses that view controller, the page with the new size would appear

Comment: "Change what you want to change". My question is how do I change it?. Like the css is one big string right? and i might need to change it at multiple places

Comment: Can you change your html? It would be easier to put a class you change on a wrapper div and use that to control your css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better if you changed a class in your html rather than try to change lots of entries in your css.
For example if you laid out your html like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper" class="med">
        <p class="calibre">Lorem Ipsum</p>
        <!--rest of html-->
    </div>
</body>
```

You could change the class in the `#wrapper`element in your backend code and then use css to determine the style for the page, like this:

```
.calibre {
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 5pt;
    margin-right: 5pt;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    text-align: justify
}
#wrapper.small .calibre{
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
#wrapper.large .calibre{
    font-size: 1.4em;
}
```

In the above example there is no specific class for med, so the default will be used (1em). If you were to make the wrapper have the class small or large instead of med, calibre would still have all the same properties except the `font-size` would change to `0.8em` in the case of small and `1.4em` in the case of large.

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/jqre2smr/1/) an example with jquery taking the place of your backend code.

Comment: I would then need the new class (for med) to have al the previous properties except the one I want change. How would I go about doing that? Thanks!

Comment: If med wasn't your default, then you could add in another bit of css like `#wrapper.med{ font-size: 1.1em;}` or whatever. The calibre class will always get everything from the long entry in the css, the `font-size` is just being overwritten in the example when the wrapper has a class of "small" or "large".

Comment: If I understand this correctly, if the text is of type #wrapper.small and has class calibre, then it will get all the properties of the calibre class and the #wrapper.small will override the properties in the calibre class.

Comment: Any html element that has the class calibre will get all the properties in the first curly braces. Then any html element with the class calibre that is also inside of a html element with the id wrapper and the class small will get what's inside the second curly braces (`font-size: 0.8em;`) This will overwrite the default for a calibre class as it is more specific.

Comment: Alright thanks. Ill mark the answer as correct since it solves the question. However,I have many classes like calibre. According to this method(creating new classes like #wrapper), Ill need to create multiple classes for each calibre class I have which each have different font sizes which I want to change (calibre1(font-size 1em), calibre2(font-size 1.3em), etc). Is there any other way in which I do not have to create many classes? Thanks

Comment: You will have to create a fair bit of css to allow for the changes to each section. If you find more than 1 element that will have the same `font-size` I'd recommend adding a class in that just handles those elements' `font-size` so you only need to change that new class to effect multiple elements.